# KAFKA to Salesforce

Tags: streaming-api

I am working on one task and that is to send data **from** KAFKA **to** Salesforce streaming api (for particular push topic).

Anyone have any idea how to do that? Any link or any code snippet would be great.

Answer (score -7):

This is very well documented in this salesforce developers website [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/05/streaming-salesforce-events-heroku-kafka.html)

The Salesforce Streaming API captures data events in Salesforce allowing subscribers to receive those events in near-realtime via an HTTP persistent connection.

```
pushTopic.Name = 'ContactUpdates';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 36.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

To consume events from a PushTopic you need a Comet client.  For this example app the Java client from cometd.org will be used to consume events in a Scala application.  A very basic event consumer would look like:

```
val bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(url, transport)
bayeuxClient.handshake()
bayeuxClient.waitFor(connectionTimeout, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED)
bayeuxClient.getChannel(s"/topic/ContactUpdates").subscribe {
  new MessageListener() {
    override def onMessage(channel: ClientSessionChannel, message: Message) {
      println(message)
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want to check the [help document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku) on this

Comment: Hello sir, salesforce events to kafka is working, i already did this. now i want to send events from kafka to salesforce.

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy can you please provide a similar example which shows send events from Kafka to salesforce.

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy The question was about how to ingest data into salesforce from Kafka. Your answer is about pushing data to a kafka topic from salesforce.